# Mount works manually but not in fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

I have 3 nfs mounts that used to work but don't work from fstab any longer but do work on other servers.

Also if I mount manually from said server they work

```
mount Server:/backup01  /backup01
```

but in fstab, with flags, it is not working:

```
Server:/nas/stage /u00/stage      nfs     rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,vers=3,timeo=600,actimeo=0 0 0
Server:/backup    /u00/backup     nfs     rw,bg,hard,intr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,noac,nfsvers=3,timeo=600    0 0
Server:/backup01  /backup01       nfs     rw,bg,hard,intr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,noac,nfsvers=3,timeo=600    0 0
```

Also note it fails silently.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Update: I went through each option and found the issue is with TCP option. Im not sure why yet as that option works on all other servers. Will keep looking but if someone can save me sometime and shed any light on why the TCP option wouldnt be working that would be great :)

Comment: It doesn't fail silently, it runs in background. NFS manual says `If the bg option is in effect, the mount command backgrounds itself and continues  to  attempt the specified mount request.`

Comment: There is any clue in logs? `/var/log/messages`'d contain some information on the mount attempts.

Comment: What happens if you try `mount -o rw,hard,intr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,noac,nfsvers=3,timeo=600 -t nfs Server:/backup01  /backup01`? Note that I used the same options of fstab line but the `bg` one.

Comment: Don't you need `uid` and `gid`?

Comment: I did turn on debugging (rpcdebug -m nfsd all ) and found these errors in /var/log/messages 

`Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr mountd[32043]: Caught signal 15, un-registering and exiting. 
Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr kernel: [519350.660146] nfsd: freeing readahead buffers. 
Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr kernel: [519350.660328] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache 
Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr kernel: [519350.746779] set_max_drc nfsd_drc_max_mem 20639744 
Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr kernel: [519350.758818] nfsd: creating service `

Comment: `Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr kernel: [519350.758818] nfsd: creating service 
Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr kernel: [519350.759707] nfsd: allocating 32 readahead buffers. 
Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr kernel: [519350.759785] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory 
Mar 24 12:56:23 iccerpdb11-dr kernel: [519350.759905] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period `

Comment: This is the error i get when i run `mount -o rw,hard,intr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,noac,nfsvers=3,time‌​o=600 -t nfs Server:/backup01 /backup01`
Bad nfs mount parameter: time..o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was with the TCP switch and found out that the backup server had been rebuilt and they didnt bind the ports, so all nfs connections were defaulting to UDP, as MOUNTD had picked up a blocked port. If you dont bind the ports when the machine is rebooted it will change the port for the below nfs components.

> To Bind the Ports;
>
> Uncomment or add these lines to /etc/sysconfig/nfs with the ports you want to use:
>
> - RQUOTAD_PORT=875
> - LOCKD_TCPPORT=32803
> - LOCKD_UDPPORT=32769
> - MOUNTD_PORT=892
> - STATD_PORT=662
>
> dont forget too restart nfs service.